# Find Date from text or any paragraph

Tags: javascript

I need to find the date from the text like I have string in this format."This cashback can be used as a discount at any Indian merchant accepting PayPal, expires on 28 September 2019. Go ahead and make your next payment with PayPal and use this cashback. Safe Hai."
From this String i need to get the date '28 September 2019' with the help of javascript as this whole string is dynamic.

Comment: will the date format be always the same ? if not what are valid format ? what did you try before coming here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below snippet to get the date from Message :

```js
var msg = '"28 November 2019 This cashback can be used as a discount at any Indian merchant accepting PayPal, expires on 28 September 2019. Go ahead and make your next payment with PayPal and use this cashback. Safe Hai."'
var oRegex = /([\d]{1,2} (?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?) [\d]{4})/gim
var match;
do {
  match = oRegex.exec(msg);
  if (match) {
    console.log(match[1]);
  }
} while (match);
```

Comment: I have modified snippet to get multiple dates from the given string - @KanikaSharma

Answer (score 0):

You may try out the [Chrono](https://github.com/wanasit/chrono) JS package as it allows parsing a wide variety of date formats like

- Today, Tomorrow, Yesterday, Last Friday, etc
- 17 August 2013 - 19 August 2013
- This Friday from 13:00 - 16.00
- 5 days ago
- 2 weeks from now
- Sat Aug 17 2013 18:40:39 GMT+0900 (JST)
- 2014-11-30T08:15:30-05:30